# Custom indexing Connector for Azure Blob not crawling

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, azure, external-blob-storage

I am creating a custom indexing connector for Azure blob. It works fine if i just specified URL for single blob e.g. for `myblob://searchconnector.blob.core.windows.net/MyBlob/mycontainer/myblob1.txt`
it just crawls `http://searchconnector.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob1.txt`.

Where `myblob` is protocol and `MyBlob` is entity type

But if i want to crawl all blobs of container using `myblob://searchconnector.blob.core.windows.net/MyContainer/mycontainer`
 then getting exception. Finder method to get blobs is called and then correct access URIs for each blob  are created by

```
GetAccessUri(IEntityInstance entityInstance, IEntityInstance parentEntityInstance)
```

after that it fails by this exception

> "Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception:
>   System.ArgumentException Internal error: Too few parameters in Method.
>   )"

Any help will be appreciated as I am not able to figure out why this exception occurs. I am following Custom File System Connector to develop this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using batching for multiple items returning from finder method.